# xcode count button on different class and use value

Tags: xcode, count

I want to know when click button on first class or second class, it will count +1 and send value in third class.

In third class I have button in scrollview as loop ( i = 1; i < 30; i++)
Then if count = 1 button at position i = 1 will show title "first" and if count = 2 button at position i = 2 will show title "second"

in first.h and second.h

```
IBOutlet UIButton*countBtn;
NSInteger tapCount;
```

in first.m and second.m

```
-(IBAction)CountButton:(id)sender{
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
tapCount += 1;
[defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:tapCount] forKey:@"buttonPress"];
}
```

in third.m

```
NSInteger i;
int x = 60;
for ( i = 1; i < 30; i++){
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.frame = CGRectMake(x, 20, 120, 120);

button.tag = i;
x = x+170;
[scrollView addSubview:button];
}

[scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
scrollView.ContentSize = CGSizeMake(5000, 130);

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *loadCount = [defaults objectForKey:@"buttonPress"];
int Count = [loadCount intValue];

if (Count = 1){

    button.tag = 1;
    [button setTitle:@"first" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else if (Count = 2){
     button.tag = 2;
    [button setTitle:@"second" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow.  At the moment your question is a bit hard to understand.. Do you think you could edit it and make you question clearer?

Comment: @trideceth12 I have edit already. Are you understand more?